# MongoDB Timeseries unusably slow queries after deleting and re-creating timeseries with auto-deletion

Tags: mongodb

My measurements:

I have 3 `measurement` types, a lot of `asset`s, and `data` with `timestamp`s. The size of the timeseries grows by ~5GB / month after compression.

My timeseries collections:

I had a blank timeseries DB initially. It was slow so I indexed it, it became actually extremely fast and handy to use. After a few months, it became too large. I couldn't delete old entries in time, so I had to drop it. It became unusable.

I have created a new one, with *automatic deletion*. I indexed it in 2 ways.

```
.createIndex({measurement:1, asset:1, timestamp:1})
```

```
.createIndex({asset:1, measurement:1, timestamp:1})
```

Each and every query for a *single asset's measurement type, limited to 1000* takes upwards of **2 minutes, if it ever returns at all**.

Example:

`{asset:"my_asset", measurement:"price"}`

`{measurement:"price", asset:"my_asset"}`

The database is unusable on arrival. It was never functional, from the very start, with or without indexing the queries were unbearably slow.

The fastest query, which sometimes returns something, I found in MongoDB Compass. Using the indexes, just querying `{asset:"my_asset"}` with all the types and without limits, seems to be faster than querying into literally the easiest index to navigate, I don't know how on earth there could be a better index and how any query can take longer than a second. Literally, having it indexed by measurement type cuts off 66% of bilions of other entries initially, then asset: narrows down the asset and how can this take longer than a second?

This is the server's snippet code that makes the call.

```
let doc = doc!{
    "measurement":measurement, //reverse order due to index measure//timest.
    "asset":asset
};
let find_options = FindOptions::builder()
    .projection(doc! {
        "timestamp": 1,
        "data": 1,
})
    .limit(1000)
    .build();
let res = coll.find(doc, find_options).await.unwrap();
```

Example of an `op`

```
{
    "type": "op",
    "host": "---",
    "desc": "---",
    "connectionId": 80806,
    "client": "---",
    "clientMetadata": {
        "driver": {
            "name": "mongo-rust-driver",
            "version": "2.3.1"
        },
        "os": {
            "type": "linux",
            "architecture": "x86_64",
            "version": "18.04"
        },
        "platform": "rustc 1.67.0-nightly (1eb62b123 2022-11-27) with tokio"
    },
    "active": "true",
    "currentOpTime": "2023-02-18T16:09:00.569+00:00",
    "effectiveUsers": [
        {
            "user": "---",
            "db": "---"
        }
    ],
    "threaded": true,
    "opid": 4359443,
    "lsid": {
        "id": "---",
        "uid": "---"
    },
    "secs_running": 1255,
    "microsecs_running": 1255159150,
    "op": "getmore",
    "ns": "MyDB.MyTS",
    "command": {
        "getMore": {
            "low": 1168443057,
            "high": 1271883998,
            "unsigned": false
        },
        "collection": "MyTS",
        "$db": "MyDB",
        "lsid": {
            "id": "---"
        },
        "$clusterTime": {
            "clusterTime": {
                "$timestamp": "7201527765789573142"
            },
            "signature": {
                "hash": "---",
                "keyId": {
                    "low": 6,
                    "high": 1669480924,
                    "unsigned": false
                }
            }
        },
        "$readPreference": {
            "mode": "primaryPreferred"
        }
    },
    "planSummary": "IXSCAN { control.min.measurement: 1, control.max.measurement: 1, control.min.asset: 1, control.max.asset: 1, control.min.timestamp: 1, control.max.timestamp: 1 }",
    "cursor": {
        "cursorId": {
            "low": 1168443057,
            "high": 1271883998,
            "unsigned": false
        },
        "createdDate": "2023-02-18T16:04:56.238Z",
        "lastAccessDate": "2023-02-18T16:05:47.456Z",
        "nDocsReturned": 0,
        "nBatchesReturned": 1,
        "noCursorTimeout": false,
        "tailable": false,
        "awaitData": false,
        "originatingCommand": {
            "aggregate": "system.buckets.MyTS",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$_internalUnpackBucket": {
                        "timeField": "timestamp",
                        "bucketMaxSpanSeconds": 86400,
                        "exclude": [],
                        "assumeNoMixedSchemaData": true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "measurement": "price",
                        "asset": "myAsset"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$limit": 1000
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "timestamp": 1,
                        "data": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "cursor": {
                "batchSize": 101
            },
            "collation": {}
        },
        "operationUsingCursorId": 4359443
    },
    "numYields": 4224,
    "locks": {},
    "waitingForLock": "false",
    "lockStats": {
        "FeatureCompatibilityVersion": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 4480
            }
        },
        "Global": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 4480
            }
        },
        "Mutex": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 256
            }
        }
    },
    "waitingForFlowControl": false,
    "flowControlStats": {}
}
```

It returned after 32 minutes. It used to take 3 seconds when under heavy load, and 1-2 on average.

Comment: What did you use as your metaField? It very important to understand the metaField aspect of the mongodb timeseries collections. In my experience if you query by fields in the metaField your queries can be extremely fast even without indecies. Are the fields "asset" and "measurement" generally static (not changing between measurements)? Could you add the output from listCollections https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-check-type/

Comment: metaField was `asset`. The `asset`s are added, and then remain. `measurement`s are a few types, always same types of measurements. The output from listCollections will be my one timeseries collection I don't have more if that's what you meant

Comment: Adding your listCollection would give me more details regarding how your time-series is configured. My bet is that there is a misconfiguration.